# Remote Desktop Connection breaks laptop's connection to network

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, remote

**Background**: I have three computers at home.  Two (XP and Windows 7) need to control a laptop (Windows 7 64bit) via RDC (over wifi).  I **can** see the computer on the network (via Explorer).

---

**Problem**: When I connect to the laptop via RDC from either of my other computers it automatically authenticates me, shows the welcome screen briefly then goes all black.  After a time it shows that the "Two computers couldn't be connected in the time allotted"

After that when i try to view the computer on the network, I get:

"Windows  cannot access .  Check the spelling of my name..."

And if try to use RDC again i get the "Remote desktop can't find the computer"

In the router it is **no longer** shown as an attached device

After about ten minutes i can then see the computer on the router and on the network (via Explorer), but still not RDC of course.

---

**Note**: This laptop is only three weeks old.  It worked well for the first two weeks, but has been doing something for the last week.  I have not installed anything, except for the Windows updates

---

**Have tried**:
- Disabling bitmap caching
- Setting the MTU size to something smaller (1400)
- Disabling IP v6 and enabling Netbios over TCP

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like firewall is temporarily blocking you.

Comment: Thanks.  I use Windows Firewall on all machines.  I tried disabling it on the laptop but received the same result.

Comment: Windows live installed? Live has caused me headache with remote logins on windows 7 until I uninstalled it.

Comment: No, it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: it was caused by the wireless profiles being "me only" instead of "all users."  The Intel wireless utility was doing this.

Essentially, when you try and log in over RDP, the logon event triggers the wireless to get disconnected if it's a "me only" wireless profile to which you're connected.